# is there any way to find address range of heap and stack allocated to an application in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, heap-memory, valgrind, stack-memory

is there any way to find the address range of heap and stack allocated to an application in Ubuntu?
I hope Valgrind or a plugin of Valgrind can help me but I didn't find it.

Comment: `cat /proc/$$/maps`?

Comment: @KamilCuk You're right. Please put your answer as an Answer so I can close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux you can inspect `/proc/[pid]/maps` file containing currently mapped regions to the process. The file also has special sections `[stack]` for stack of main process, `[stack:<tid>]` for thread tid stack and `[heap]` for process heap. For more info, see `man 5 proc`.